# how to set values in bitfield set variables in a structure?

Tags: qt, struct, bit-fields

I have written the code below on Qt,when I put values in it it program.exe stops working.

```
struct aim
{
   int i : 1;
   int j : 1;
};

    int main()
    {
       aim missed;
       printf("Enter value of i :: ");
       scanf("%u",missed.i);

       printf("Enter value of j :: ");
       scanf("%u",missed.j);
    }
```

can anyone help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the C/C++ standard does not allow to access the members of a bitfield via a pointer and you have to pass scanf a pointer.

Comment: then what should I use in place of scanf

Comment: To read a variable into a c bitfield I think you have to save it in a temporary variable you can get a pointer to and then copy it to the bitfield (and check if the value is valid for it)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. A 1-bit signed integer isn't very useful, it can only hold the values -1 and 0.
2. You can't have a pointer to a bit-field, that's not what pointers mean.
3. Also, there's nothing in the `%d` specifier that tells the `scanf()` function that the target value is a bit field (nor is there any other `%` specifier that can do this, see 2).

The solution is to `scanf()` to a temporary variable, range-check the received value, then store it in the bit field.

Comment: Additional remark: A pointer so a bitfield member would not even be possible at all because pointers are holding byte-adresses and bitfield members may have "fractional-byte" adresses.